# how to change the scrollbar style on iOS safari?

Tags: html, ios, css

for the project need,i have to change my html page scrollbar style.
here is my css profile:

```
.txt_Content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:5px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.txt_Content::-webkit-scrollbar-button    {
    display: none;
}
.txt_Content::-webkit-scrollbar-track     {
    background:#e5e2ad;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.txt_Content::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background:#e5e2ad;
    border-radius:4px;
    border: 1px solid #c5b481;

}
.txt_Content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background:#fbfae3;
    border-radius:4px;
    border: 1px solid #c5b481;
}
.txt_Content::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    border-radius:4px;
}
.txt_Content::-webkit-resizer  {
    display: none;
}
```

and this is my html profile:

```
<div class="txt_border">
    <img src="../image/txt_border2.png">
    <ul class="txt_Content">
        <li class="biaoqian">
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <p>txtxt</p>
                <p>txtxtxt</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!---->
    </ul>
</div>
```

it works great in chrome on mac and android phone:
http://i1.piimg.com/567571/033a19c05f29073b.png

but it doesn't work on iphone:
http://i1.piimg.com/567571/7938a2c5681f740f.png

is there any problem with mycode?or the mobile safari doesn't surpport the css3 ?

Comment: Actually, iOS Safari support CSS scrollbar style, please check: https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20scrollbar

Comment: Your code works well on iOS9, please check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/2Lvtg7pp/

Answer (score -1):

actually, Scrollbar styling doesn’t work in WKWebView from the canIuse